# Print all enabled items within a list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

This is what my code does.
 (1.) Open chrome browser and go to footlocker.ca
 (2.) Click on the Mens button
 (3.) Select 1 random product from the list of 60
 (4.) Print the product name and price
 (5.) Print all available sizes for the selected product (avaSizes)
 (6.) Go back to the products page
 (7.) Select a 2nd random product from the list of 60
 (8.) Print the product name and price
 (9.) Print all available sizes for the selected product (avaSizes)
 (10.) Close chrome browser

My problem is that it fails to read the available sizes for the product. I think my problem is in the xpath but I am not to sure as I have tinkered with various xpath's so it may be my code that is the problem. The method is called (avaSizes). If someone can help it would be great. I am doing this for practice so if anyone has some real time job scenario test cases that I could add on to this code it would help me a lot. Thanks.

```
public class FootlockerExample {

WebElement next;
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

public void productOne (){

    // Open Chrome Browser
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Working\\Workspace\\SeleniumProject\\chromedriver.exe");

    // Open Footlocker website and maximize window
    driver.get("http://www.footlocker.ca/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Find button element 'Mens' and click
    next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='global-nav']/ul/li[1]/a"));
    next.click();

    // Select a random product
    selectRandomProduct();

    // Print out the product name and price
    String productName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[1]")).getText();
    String Price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[2]")).getText(); 
    System.out.println("The 1st randomly selected product is " + productName + " and it's cost is " + Price + ".");

    // Print all available product sizes
    avaSizes();

    // Execute new method
    productTwo();
}

public void productTwo(){

    // Go back a browser page
    driver.navigate().back();

    // Select a new random product
    selectRandomProduct();

    // Print out the product name and price
    String productName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[1]")).getText();
    String Price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[2]")).getText(); 
    System.out.println("The 2nd randomly selected product is " + productName + " and it's cost is " + Price + ".");

    // Print all available product sizes
    avaSizes();

    driver.close();
}

public void selectRandomProduct(){

    // Find and click on a random product
    List<WebElement> allProducts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='endecaResultsWrapper']/div[3]//img"));
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomProduct = rand.nextInt(allProducts.size());
    allProducts.get(randomProduct).click();
}

public void avaSizes(){

    // Find all the available shoe sizes for each randomly selected product
    List<WebElement> avaSizes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_sizes']"));
    int totalSizes = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<avaSizes.size(); i++){
        if(avaSizes.get(i).isEnabled()==true){
            avaSizes.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(avaSizes);
            totalSizes++;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Out of stock in all sizes.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("This product is available in: " + totalSizes + " sizes.");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FootlockerExample obj1 = new FootlockerExample();
    obj1.productOne();
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the HTML code.

Comment: @ShubhasmitGupta I fixed the issue with the help of Marius D. Added his code to my logic and it works. Thanks however for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from Marius D above, I have figured out the problem and fixed my code. 
Here is my fixed answer for future in case someone is stuck on the same issue.

```
    public void avaSizes(){
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("product_sizes"))); 
    // Find all the available shoe sizes for each randomly selected product
    List<WebElement> avaSizes = select.getOptions(); 
    int totalSizes = 0;
    for(WebElement size:avaSizes){
        if(size.isEnabled()==true){
            System.out.println(size.getText());
            totalSizes++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Out of stock in " + size.getText());
                }
        }
    System.out.println("This product is available in: " + totalSizes + " sizes.");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I see that the dropdown element has an id and is of type Select.
You can work with it using the [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) object:

```
 Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("product_sizes")));      
 List<WebElement> availableSizes = select.getOptions();

   for (WebElement size : availableSizes) {
        System.out.println(size.getText());
   }
```

Comment: I need it to only print the sizes that are enabled. Lets for ShoeA there are sizes 9,10, 11, 12, 13 but it's only available or in stock for 10, and 12 so it should print 10, 12 instead of getting all the options under the Select tag. From what I see in this code it prints out all the sizes, doesn't take under considerate if the option is disabled or not.